# Get HTML tags with its class name in an array

Tags: php, regex

i want to fetch all the html tags with its class name in an array.
like

```
< a class="abc"></a>, < h2 class="xyz"> </h2>
```

I want `<a>` and `abc` and `<h2>` and `xyz` in an array. i am unable to find any logic to get it. i am trying  `preg_replace` and  `preg_replace_all` but couldn't get any solution.

Comment: Look into DOM functions in PHP

Comment: try this preg_match_all('/(.*?)\sclass="(.*?)">(.*?)<\/(.*?)>/is',$yourstring,$matches);
echo "<pre>".print_r($matches,true);

Answer (score 0):

Someone smart once said that you should not filter the dom yourself, it does not matter how skilled you are with regex... So do not do it.

Anyhow:

```
$html = 'Foobar <a href="link" class="abc" style="sda">anchor</a>,space <h2 class="xyz">heading</h2>text betewwn <a href="foo">anchor 2</a>';
preg_match_all('|<a[^>]*(?:class=["'."'".']([^"'."'".']*)["'."'".'])[^>]*>(.*?)<\/a>|sim', $html, $matches);
var_dump($matches);

// Output: 
array(3) {
  [0] =>
  array(1) {
    [0] =>
    string(49) "<a href="link" class="abc" style="sda">anchor</a>"
  }
  [1] =>
  array(1) {
    [0] =>
    string(3) "abc"
  }
  [2] =>
  array(1) {
    [0] =>
    string(6) "anchor"
  }
}
```

This will find all a-taggs with classes.

Comment: thanks for answer but i want all tag not only a tag.

Comment: "This will find all a-taggs with classes."